# Is there any pure PHP implementation of LZMA

Tags: php, shared-hosting, lzma

So I'm building a web app to decompress an LZMA compressed CSV file and then let the user edit it, when saved it will be recompressed.

I have the code to compress/decompress in C# using the 7-Zip LZMA SDK, but with my hosting plan I can't use exec() to call the exe.

Is there any pure php implementation of LZMA I could use? Or if not is there any way to convert the C# code into php code?

Comment: There isn't one, no. Without access to exec on your host I think you may be out of luck here.

Comment: Okay thank you, I was just checking to see if anyone had any knowledge on the subject.

Comment: There's been some discussion of it in the past, but it's always seemed to settle on everyone wanting a decent native implementation, but nobody wanting it enough to write one :(